# FFMPEG 2 Channel AIF files = fail

Tags: php, terminal, ffmpeg

I wonder if anyone has a solution for AIF files that are "2 Channels", which do not compile in ffmpeg. But if you take the same aif file and open it up in a editor and recompile it as Stereo (L R), it works as expected.

My `ffmpeg` command and console output:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.aif -ar 44100 -ab 128k -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -y output.mp3
ffmpeg version 2.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar  2 2014 19:58:58 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 38.100 / 52. 38.100
  libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
  libavformat    55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 79.101 /  3. 79.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[aiff @ 0x1d94940] ID3v2.32 tag skipped, cannot handle version
input.aif: Input/output error
```

Comment: What created these AIFF files that are not working as expected? Please provide a sample input file so others can attempt to duplicate this issue.

Comment: [link](http://tunespring.com/Sandbox/ID/imagineddesign.aif) [link](http://tunespring.com/Sandbox/ID/imagineddesignStereo.aif)---

I added a stereo = works, 

I added a 2 channel = fail

Comment: @LordNeckbeard these files were created in [protools](http://www.avid.com/us/products/family/pro-tools/)

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how you edit the file to make it work in `ffmpeg`?

Comment: I edit a file in any audio file and then upload it to a site and ffmpeg runs. Seems to be an issue with .aif or .aiff files that are 2 channel. if I set them to Stereo (L R) they are fine.